# IBM x346 won't POST

Tags: hardware, boot, ibm

I've got an IBM x346 that was (supposedly) working fine in the past which will no longer post now that I've taken it back out of storage.

When I power it up, it seems to be permanently stuck in an endless cycle of almost posting and then reseting. It doesn't get to the beep codes, but does periodically flash the boot logo momentarily on the attached monitor, and the 2x8 segment post display is in constant flux. If I remove the memory, it properly lights up the missing module indicators (by the dimm and on the lightpath), and emits the out of memory beep code. It does the same thing if I install dual-rank dimms (obviously, this machine shouldn't support that).

I've pulled all the acccessory cards and risers that can reasonably be removed, taken out the drives, and still this endless post cycle. I've tried both power supply modules. I don't have another similar machine handy, or I'd start swapping in the more important bits.

Any advice on where to look next? Anyone else seen this behavior?

Comment: Just tried clearing the CMOS and reseating the CPUs. No change.

Comment: Might be bad memory. If it will run on just one stick (not familiar with this model), try one at a time, and try it in different slots). Also, as Izzy said, reseat everything with a socket possible.

Also, blow out any dust, especially down in the empty memory slots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further investigation has revealed that it wasn't any of those previous ideas at all.

Apparently the system will not stay powered (and thus will not boot) if the POWER cable connecting the PSU to the SCSI backplane is not fully and completely seated. It had worked its way loose, and seems to have been the root cause of the problem. The data cable can be completely absent without problems.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the CMOS backup battery and clear CMOS.

Comment: No luck with this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reseating the CPU(s)?

Comment: This didn't seem to change anything.